Proof of the statement "the best test is unbiased"
There is a corollary from Hogg and McKean's textbook titled "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics" and I have miserably failed to understand the proof. Unfortunately, my question requires me to also type in relevant definitions and theorems. I have added that towards the end of the post as an appendix.
Corollary 8.1.1. As in Theorem 8.1.1, let $C$ be the critical region of the best test of $H_0 : \theta = \theta'$ versus $H_1 : \theta = \theta''$. Suppose the significance level of the test is $\alpha$. Let $\gamma_C (\theta'') = P_{\theta''} [\pmb{X} \in C]$ denote the power of the test. Then $\alpha \leq \gamma_C (\theta'').$
Proof: Consider the “unreasonable” test in which the data are ignored, but a Bernoulli trial is performed which has probability $\alpha$ of success. If the trial ends in success, we reject $H_0$. The level of this test is $\alpha$. Because the power of a test is the probability of rejecting $H_0$ when $H_1$ is true, the power of this unreasonable test is $\alpha$ also. But $C$ is the best critical region of size $\alpha$ and thus has power greater than or equal to the power of the unreasonable test. That is, $\gamma_C (\theta'') \geq \alpha$, which is the desired result.$~~\blacksquare$
Where does it break for me?
What the heck is an "unreasonable" test? How can you put this mathematically? Speaking specifically about his argument,

He bases accept/reject decision based on a coin toss with probability of success $=\alpha$ irrespective of where the samples lie. How does that make the level of this test equal to $\alpha$ when you are not involving the logic of whether or not $X$ is in $C$ or not? You cannot ignore it because all of his definitions require that to be evaluated.

Now irrespective of whether $H_0$ is true or $H_1$ is true, decision is based on a coin toss whose probability of success is $\alpha$. Is that the reason why the power is also $\alpha$?

Most important for me is the claim in the last line of the proof. He says $C$ is the best critical region and hence has power greater than or equal to that of the unreasonable test. If you look at the definition 8.1.1, he compares powers of tests with critical region $C$ and any other region $A$ which implicitly assumes that we are looking at probability that the samples are in the critical region or not. There is no scope for tests which ignore the location of the samples with respect to the critical region as is done in this so called unreasonable test. So what exactly is he doing here?


I tried to look at an alternative proof for this and could not find it. Any help in understanding this or better yet, if you can point me to an airtight mathematical proof of this corollary, I'd greatly appreciate it.
Appendix -- Relevant definitions and theorems:
Hypothesis: We are interested in a random variable $X$ that has pdf or pmf $f(x;\theta),$ where $\theta \in \Omega.$ We assume that $\theta \in \omega_0$ or $\theta \in \omega_1$, where $\omega_0$ and $\omega_1$ are disjoint subsets of $\Omega$ and $\omega_0 \cup \omega_0 = \Omega.$ We label the hypotheses as
$$H_0 : \theta \in \omega_0 ~\text{versus}~H_1 : \theta \in \omega_1. \tag{8.1.1}$$
Definition 8.1.1. Let $C$ denote a subset of the sample space. Then we say that $C$ is a best critical region of size $\alpha$ for testing the simple hypothesis $H_0 : \theta = \theta'$ against the alternative simple hypothesis $H_1 : \theta = \theta''$ if
(a) $P_{\theta'}[X \in C]=\alpha.$
(b) And for every subset $A$ of the sample space,
$$P_{\theta'} [X \in A] = \alpha \implies P_{\theta''}[X \in C] \geq P_{\theta''}[X \in A].$$
Theorem 8.1.1. Neyman–Pearson Theorem. Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots , X_n,$ where $n$ is a fixed positive integer, denote a random sample from a distribution that has pdf or pmf $f(x;\theta).$ Then the likelihood of $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ is
$$L(\theta;\pmb{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i;\theta), ~\text{for}~ \pmb{x'} = (x_1,\cdots,x_n).$$
Let $\theta'$ and $\theta''$ be distinct fixed values of $\theta$ so that $\Omega = \{\theta:\theta=\theta',\theta''\},$ and let $k$ be a positive number. Let $C$ be a subset of the sample space such that
(a) $\frac{L(\theta';x)}{L(\theta'';x)} \leq k,$ for each point $x \in C.$
(b) $\frac{L(\theta';x)}{L(\theta'';x)} \geq k,$ for each point $x \in C^c.$
(c) $\alpha = P_{H_0}[X \in C].$
Then $C$ is a best critical region of size $\alpha$ for testing the simple hypothesis $H_0 : \theta = \theta'$ against the alternative simple hypothesis $H_1 : \theta = \theta''.$
Definition 8.1.2. Let $X$ be a random variable which has pdf or pmf $f(x;\theta),$ where $\theta \in \Omega.$ Consider the hypotheses given in expression $(8.1.1).$ Let $\pmb{X'} = (X_1, \cdots , X_n)$ denote a random sample on $\pmb{X}$. Consider a test with critical region $C$ and level $\alpha$. We say that this test is unbiased if
$$P_{\theta}(X \in C) \geq \alpha,$$
for all $\theta \in \omega_1.$

My guess is that they are working with the following bit of underlying logic, but they have probably failed to explain it to you.

The space of tests is a convex space. You can combine two tests by flipping a coin (with probability $p$) and choosing either one or the other depending on the value of the coin flip.

These combinations are such that their level and power are the linear combinations of the level and power of the two combined tests.

The space of tests contains the following trivial tests:

the trivial test always answering $H_0$.
the trivial test always answering $H_1$.
the trivial tests flipping a coin to decide whether they answer $H_0$ or $H_1$. This is the linear combination of the first two trivial tests.



Now, here is a proof of their result. I'm not quite sure whether that's exactly what they meant, but it seems similar?

A: they consider the optimal test with level $\alpha$. This is the test with maximal power given that it has level $\alpha$.

B: Then, they exhibit a test which trivially has level $\alpha$ and has power $\gamma = \alpha$.

C: they conclude that the optimal test must have better power than the trivial test.


I hope this helps.
The result on combinations of tests is quite important:

it explains why the ROC curve is typically concave.
it is technically necessary in some cases with discrete variables. Otherwise, it might be impossible to have a test with level $\alpha$ and that breaks all sorts of proofs.

but, you are right to point out that, in real-life, randomized tests are very silly. In practice, we are perfectly fine if the practical level is not quite at $\alpha$.

Thanks for the answer. After you mentioned space of tests, I searched for it and this is new to me (not covered in this text). Nevertheless I followed some parts of the proof you have given. The part I have a problem with is the statement "C:" where optimal test must have a power better than that of the trivial test. As you can see in the Definition 8.1.1 part (b), $C$ is the best critical region when it has the highest power among all other critical regions $A$ of size $\alpha$. In fact, there has been no mention of "optimal test" or "best test" at all. Only "best critical region".

In fact, the hypothesis of Corollary 8.1.1 clearly mentions the kind of hypothesis tests that are being considered namely $H_0 : \theta = \theta'$ versus $H_1 : \theta = \theta''$. The best critical region requires us to evaluate $P_\theta[X \in A]$. In his unreasonable test, I'd write the hypothesis as $H_0 : \text{Coin Flip is Tails}$ versus  $H_1 : \text{Coin Flip is Heads}$. This does not involve $\theta$ so this is not even a contender for us to apply definition 8.1.1 right?

It's like saying definition: Pythagorean Triplets $={(a,b,c): a^2+b^2 = c^2, ~ a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}}$ and then saying "consider the trivial triplet $(i,1,0)$" where i is the imaginary number -- we can conclude that c can be zero for non-zero a and b!

My terminology is probably not quite the same as theirs. Try looking for "randomized tests". They briefly discuss it on page 279 https://minerva.it.manchester.ac.uk/~saralees/statbook2.pdf

After some consideration, I think their approach is indeed a bit loose. Their proof would work fine if you add a new Bernoulli parameter on top of the data. You can now define the best critical region on that new bigger space. The best critical region must be better than the trivial test which only looks at the coin flip but ignores the data. However, there's a slight non-sequitur of whether the best test can be represented as an indicator of some critical region (and, interestingly, it can't in full generality: you need randomization)

Wrapping up, you are right to say that this proof is loose, but the result is correct: for non pathological tests, the power is higher than the level. I would advise you to move on and not remain stuck on this point. It's not that unusual for reference textbooks to have small mistakes in their claims or proofs. If you want to check out another reference, I recommend the casella berger book.

I too felt that it is loose. This is not like them. None of their material has been this way. When a mathematical proof is given and when it is airtight, there would not be any scope for such confusion. I have read this proof a ton of times and I just could not reconcile with the fact that they applied definition 8.1.1 that involved their "unreasonable test" that has nothing to do with either the critical region or the parameters.

Thanks for the confirmation. I will check out C&B for this corollary.

C&B probably don't have this exact corollary. This is a very minor result, even though it is somewhat interesting.  In defense of H&MK, what's probably going on is that they want to focus on non-randomized tests, because these are clearly the sensible tests. But then, you run into weird issues. Instead of addressing them, they swept them slightly under the rug, resulting in a bad proof. Such things happen when writing a text book: you want to focus on understandable constructs, and sometimes that makes you sacrifice some mathematical precision.

Got it. I will check with other textbooks for the proof. If they don't have it, they might have something else that might help me construct the proof myself. Thanks once again for the feedback.

I like my first answer, because it tries to explain the logic of the authors.
However, I was frustrated this morning because a constructive proof is actually much better, even though it quickly becomes quite involved.
Here is one such constructive proof. I am constructing the optimal test (even though I'm not proving that it is the optimal test) and showing that it respects the desired property. Along the way, I make some simplifying assumptions. These are made so that I don't need to worry about bringing in measure theory in the proofs. I leave the general case to the interested reader. Just be careful that, in the general case, there might not exist an optimal non-randomized test with level $\alpha$.
The final step of the proof is a bit cursed. I wish I had something better there, but I don't.
Final note: if anybody reading this struggles to understand the proof: don't worry about it. This proof is honestly quite involved and peculiar, as results in statistics can quickly become. You do not need to understand this proof to understand mathematical statistics. This is a very minor point.

A constructive proof
Let's build a sensible test which proves that the optimal test must have power greater than level.
Assume that $X$ is a continuous random variable and that we have two models with densities $f_0(x)$ and $f_1(x)$. We wish to construct tests of whether $X$ was generated with $f_0$ or $f_1$.
To simplify, further assume that both densities are strictly positive.
Consider the likelihood ratio:
$$
r(x) = \frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)} > 0
$$
and let $R$ be the associated random variable.
To simplify, assume that $R$ is a continuous RV with densities $g_0$ and $g_1$.
Then, the tests $R \leq t$ have level and power:
$$
\text{level} = \int_t^\infty g_0(r) dr
$$
$$
\text{power} = \int_t^\infty g_1(r) dr
$$
Critically, we have the following equality:
$$
g_1(r) = r g_0(r)
$$
Proof:
$$
\begin{align}
g_0(r) &= \int \mathbf 1( r(x) = r) f_0(x) dx \\
g_1(r) &= \int \mathbf 1( r(x) = r) f_1(x) dx \\
       &= \int \mathbf 1( r(x) = r) \frac{f_1(x)}{f_0(x)} f_0(x) dx \\
       &= r g_0(r)
\end{align}
$$
from which we can finally conclude that the power of this test is always above its level.
Proof:
NB: I wish I had something good here, but I can only offer the following cursed proof.
Consider the function:
$$
c(\lambda) = \log \int_{t \geq 0} \mathbf 1 (r \geq t) r^\lambda g_0(r) dr
$$
It interpolates between the log-level and the log-power of the test $R \geq t$. If we can show that it is increasing in $\lambda$, we have the desired result.
It turns out that it's derivative is: (NB: this is a standard result of the analysis of exponential families; I'm not proving it; it follows quickly from the straightforward proof).
$$
c'(\lambda) = \text{cov} (\mathbf 1 (r \geq t), \log r; \lambda)
$$
The covariance is computed with respect to the density:
$$
h(r;\lambda) = \frac{r^\lambda g_0(r)}{\int_{t \geq 0} r^\lambda g_0(r)}
$$
Since $\mathbf 1 (r \geq t), \log r$ are both increasing functions of $r$, the covariance is positive, and we have the desired result.

Unlike you, I like your second answer. In a mathematically rigorous fashion, you have given a proof which I think is airtight (can't say with certainty because I do not understand the nitty gritty details of the last proof even though I get most of it). It was a teeny bit confusing because we usually denote $\alpha$ to significance level. I don't think that is the case here. I wonder how you came up with the interpolation function $c(\alpha)$. That was brilliant.

As regards to just one small (intentional) gap in that proof about increasing covariance, this answer on math SE (especially the attached pdf file in the comments) might help folks who wish to fill that gap. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/74681/145325

Finally, kindly confirm the following. To show that power $\geq$ level, all we need to show is that $\int_t^\infty r g_0(r)dr \geq \int_t^\infty g_0(r)dr$ $\forall t \geq 0$ right? You have done that using the interpolation function but the end game is to show $\int_t^\infty r g_0(r)dr \geq \int_t^\infty g_0(r)dr$ $\forall t \geq 0$ right?


I'm happy if you like the proof, but it is way too painful for such an elementary result. 2. I'll change $\alpha$ to $\lambda$. That's the more usual notation for the natural parameter of an exponential family.  3. Your restatement is correct, yes.


Regarding the use of the interpolation function, it's a very useful trick. I should write a detailed guide on it on my blog at some point. I had to re-discover it on my own, but I'm certain that it would have been obvious to old time statisticians. Sadly, the knowledge around cumulant generating functions and exponential families has fallen out of style and is a bit lost currently.

That would be great! Such tutorials alongside studying HMC type of texts really adds a lot to our learning.

I thought of a proof for the statement $\int_t^\infty rg_0(r)dr \geq \int_t^\infty g_0(r)dr.$ Please correct me if I am wrong. As $g_1(r) = rg_0(r)$, we have $\int_0^\infty rg_0(r)dr = \int_0^\infty g_0(r)dr = 1$. Now consider $H(t) = \int_t^\infty (r-1)g_0(r)dr$. Then $H(0) = \lim_{t \to \infty}H(t) = 0$. As $H'(t) = (1-t)g_0(t)$, we can infer that starting from $H(0)=0$, $H(t)$ monotonically increases till $t=1$ and then monotonically decreases thereafter to $0$ as $t \to \infty.$ In the process, it is never negative.

Hence $H(t) \geq 0$ for $t \in (0,\infty)$ so that $\int_t^\infty rg_0(r)dr \geq \int_t^\infty g_0(r)dr,~ \forall t \geq 0.$ Is this argument correct?

Now that's a much better proof! Great job finding that.

About the proof with the additional Bernoulli trial

How does that make the level of this test equal to $\alpha$ when you are not involving the logic of whether or not $X$ is in $C$ or not?

That's why it is an unreasonable test. The data $X$ and region $C$ are ignored and instead some additional data $Y$ (the Bernoulli trial) that is independent from $\theta$ is considered.
The test has an $\alpha$ significance level, because that's the type I error probability (the probability of rejection of the null given that the null hypotheses is true) which for that unreasonable test becomes equal to the Bernoulli trial success probability.

There is no scope for tests which ignore the location of the samples with respect to the critical region as is done in this so called unreasonable test. So what exactly is he doing here?

The unreasonable test doesn't ignore the samples. It augmented the sample with the Bernoulli trial (as a sort of thought experiment) and uses the samples in a very silly way.
It is not ignoring the samples but you have to consider the right sample. The argument is changing the sample.
"Suppose we had instead of the samples $\mathbf{X} = \{ x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n \}$, the samples $\mathbf{X'}  = \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1} \}$ which has a Bernoulli test $x_{n+1} \sim \mathcal{B}(\alpha)$ augmented to the original samples. For this sample, a critical region $C'$ that uses the Bernoulli test would be an $\alpha$ level test and has power $\alpha$. But using the critical region $C$ has at least as large power as the critical region $C'$ because the use of region $C$ provides the most powerful test".
So the argument is initially for a different sample $\mathbf{X'}$, where the power of the region $C$ is larger than the power for the region $C'$. The fact that the power of the region $C$ is the same for $\mathbf{X}$ as for $\mathbf{X'}$ makes it irrelevant that we used the thought experiment with the sample $\mathbf{X'}$.
It is a thought experiment where we consider a very badly performing test. The power of that test is $\alpha$, so the power of the best test, based on a best critical region $C$, must be at least as good.
If you are still puzzled, why doesn't this test with region $C'$ use more information, why did it ignore the $\mathbf{X}$ part in the $\mathbf{X'}$ sample? That's the whole point, it is not a good practice and an unreasonable test. And... for such a silly unreasonable test you get a power that equals the significance level, so this should be the bare minimum of power performance for the best test.
Visual viewpoint
Consider samples distributed as
$$T \sim N(\theta,1) \\ Y \sim U(0,1)$$
then the distribution for hypotheses $H_0: \theta = 0$ and $H_1: \theta = 1$ look like below

In the plots we have shown two critical rejection regions (the gray areas) for a test with $\alpha = 0.1$ significance level.
On the left we have a unreasonable test where $power = \alpha$ on the right we have the best test were $power > \alpha$.
For any sample we can always make a thought experiment with extended data where there is this unreasonable region. Therefore, the best test must always have power at least as high as alpha.

More direct proof
You can also argue more directly that
$$\alpha = P(\textbf{X} \in C|H_0) \leq P(\textbf{X} \in C|H_1) = \text{power}$$
Proof: consider the contrary and asume that
$$P(\textbf{X} \in C|H_0) > P(\textbf{X} \in C|H_1) \\ \text{and as a consequence} \\ P(\textbf{X} \in C^\complement|H_0) < P(\textbf{X} \in C^\complement|H_1) $$
where $C^\complement$ is the complement of $C$. In that case, there must be places in the region $C$ where the likelihood ratio is above $1$ and there must be places in $C^\complement$ where the likelihood ratio is below $1$. But that contradicts with $C$ being the region with the lowest likelihood ratio.

Thank you for the proof. Short, sweet and airtight. But I still do not agree with your statement "The unreasonable test doesn't ignore the samples." When the decision is based off of $\pmb{Y}$ ignoring $\pmb{X}$, it just breaks for me. I know exactly as to where it breaks. The hypothesis $H_0$ and $H_1$ make assumptions about the parameter $\theta$ as being equal to one of two (quite clearly stated in the corollary 8.1.1), which then means distribution of $\pmb{X}$ is fixed, and we make the decision between $H_0:\theta=\theta'$ and $H_1:\theta=\theta''$ based on whether $\pmb{X} \in C$ or not.

The "unreasonable test" is making the decision based on probability of success of the Bernoulli trial (based on random variable $\pmb{Y}$). How exactly do you fit this analytically into the hypothesis $H_0:\theta = \theta'$? We cannot change the nature of hypothesis because there is no scope for it. This entire line of definitions, theorems and corollaries are based on choosing between one of two parameters based on the region in which $\pmb{X}$ lies, and the only thing we can vary is the critical region $A$. Authors should not have introduced some other arbitrary test to make the argument.

I'd really like to see someone make this whole "unreasonable test" argument completely analytical so that we do not have any scope for further arguments once we have an airtight analytical proof for the same.

@TryingHardToBecomeAGoodPrSlvr it is not ignoring the samples but you have to consider the right sample. The argument is changing the sample: "Suppose we had instead of the samples $\mathbf{X}$, the samples $\mathbf{X'}$ which has a Bernoulli test augmented, then a $\alpha$ level test critical region $C'$ would be to use the Bernoulli test and has power $\alpha$ but the critical region $C$ has at least as large power because it provides the most powerful test". So the argument is for a different sample $\mathbf{X'}$, but the power of the region is the same for $\mathbf{X}$.

If you see "Theorem 8.1.1. Neyman–Pearson Theorem." that I directly quoted from the text, it starts with "Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots , X_n,$ where $n$ is a fixed positive integer, denote a random sample from a distribution that has pdf or pmf $f(x;\theta).$" So $n$ is fixed! How then can you augment it? I can see that if the authors defined the hypothesis differently to be able to accommodate for the so called "unreasonable test" or to be able to augment data with any length of additional data, then we had some basis for their proof. The way things are defined currently, that can't be done.

@TryingHardToBecomeAGoodPrSlvr  The proof uses a different sample $X_1, X_2, \cdots , X_n, X_{n+1}$ where $X_{n+1}$ is the Bernoulli trial. But it doesn't matter that they changed the sample. The power of the region $C$ is the same for both samples, with or without the Bernoulli trial. So if you can show power ≥ alpha for the different sample, then it is also true for the original sample.

Sir I completely agree with you in that the intuitive argument works. Thanks for the visual explanation! The place where it matters that they changed the sample size is simply in the rigor of the proofs. In a mathematical statistics book, you'd expect rigor in proofs and I am just saying that their proof is not rigorous simply because the way they have defined the hypothesis, and the critical region, it just does not let us augment the sample size. Once again, thanks a bunch for the visual explanation and more importantly for giving us the alternate rigorous proof. :)

@TryingHardToBecomeAGoodPrSlvr they changed the sample by introducing the Bernoulli trial, but that doesn't make the proof less rigorous. Based on the Bernoulli trial, which may be independent of $\theta$, you can define a hypothesis test. There is nothing technically wrong with that, it doesn't break the hypotheses when the data is independent from those hypotheses. It is only a very unreasonable test because power and significance level are the same (ie it is a very bad test).
